# Pointer Released On RichEditBox UWP

Tags: uwp, richeditbox

I would like to use the PointerReleased event in a RichEditBox but it does not work.

Xaml:

```
<RichEditBox x:Name="RebText" PointerReleased="RebText_PointerReleased"/>
```

Xaml.cs:

```
private void RebText_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reson it doesn't work:**

`PointerRoutedEventArgs` has a [`Handled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.pointerroutedeventargs.handled#Windows_UI_Xaml_Input_PointerRoutedEventArgs_Handled) `bool` Property. If any `PointerEventHandler` marks this `Handled` as true, the event handler chain doesn't proceed anymore.

Now, the designer of the `RichEditBox` control had to hook the `PointerReleased` event for some obvious reason, and in the handler, he must have marked the `Handled` to true. As a result, the handler you added to the event won't be invoked.

This also happens in other controls. An example is: you can't hook the `PointerWheelChanged` event of a `ScrollViewer` by just simply adding an `EventHandler` to it, like :

```
myScrollViewer.PointerWheelChanged += Some_Handler;
```

The handler will be added, but it won't be invoked for the same reason.

**Solution:**

All `UIElement`s have an [AddHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.addhandler#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_AddHandler_Windows_UI_Xaml_RoutedEvent_System_Object_System_Boolean_) method. This method also adds `EventHandler`s to events, just like the `+=` operator does, but the benefit is, you can:

> have the provided handler be invoked even if the event is handled
>   elsewhere

So, what you should do is, something like:

```
RebText.AddHandler(RichEditBox.PointerReleasedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(RebText_PointerReleased), true);
```

and then define `RebText_PointerReleased`:

```
private void RebText_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // your event handling code here
}
```

The third argument is where you specified that you want this handler to be invoked even if the event is marked handled.

**Note:**, it's not a good practice to handle an already handled event, because, as the doc says:

> Do not routinely ask to rehandle a routed event, because it interferes
>   with the intended design of the Windows Runtime event system for
>   control compositing.